# CMS blocks does not works on Products using Custom Layout Update field in Categories

Tags: magento-1.7, category, cms-block

I would like to apply a CMS Block only for products in a specific Category. And I wish to shows it up only at Black Friday's week.

My luck is that I can set the Custom Layout Update field in my Category's admin page. And setting "Apply to All Products" to Yes should works as I'm expecting.

Well I've created my Cms block, but cant show my block in product page.
Next the layout code used in "Custom Layout Update" field, on parent Category:

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="cms/block" name="friday.price" before="-">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>friday_banner</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

All things works very well when I set another block (not custom cms).
Anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

product.info is catalog/product_view type which as I can see is not a structural block

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

so you have to call it directly where you like to display it in catalog/product/view.phtml by:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('friday.price'); ?>
```

If you are doing this through the admin panel in category custom design tab you have to remove this:

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
```

Enter/fill in only this:

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="cms/block" name="friday.price">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>friday_banner</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: But referencing "content" block does not works too. It's a structural block, right?!

Comment: I can't understand you. What exactly are you asking? If you don't change your code and only add this `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('friday.price'); ?>` in catalog/product/view.phtml - it should work.

Comment: Sorry I'll update the question to clarify my doubt (5 min...)

Comment: Please read again, and sorry by my bad english.

Comment: Please read my answer again (I updated it).

Comment: Thanks man! It works for structural blocks only as you described. But works. Unfortunately I cant use "product.info", but I will try to find another blocks like "alert.urls", "extrahint", etc. Thanks again